# Is it possible to add names to edge quotes?

Tags: labels, edge

The following MWE works as expected:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (0,0) edge node[auto] (label) {label} (1,1);
  \draw (label.south west) rectangle (label.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

however, when I try to replace code line

```
\path (0,0) edge node[auto] (label) {label} (1,1);;
```

with

```
\path (0,0) edge ["label",name=label] (1,1);
```

I get error "no shape named fr0 is not known" ...

I expected, that according to description in TikZ manual (pp 237) should be possible to add a name to quotes:

> In detail, when the quotes library is loaded, each time a key–value
>   pair in a list of options passed to an edge or a to path command
>   starts with ", the key–value pair must actually be a string of the
>   following  form:
>
> `"<text>"’<options>`
>
> This string is transformed into the following:
>
> `edge node=node [every edge quotes]<options>]{<text>}`

*Questions*:

- is possible to add a name to edge quote, which can be later used as coordinates as shown in above image?
- if it is possible, how to do this?

Comment: Your code doesn't match the specified syntax. And that example is hardly minimal!

Comment: of course not, otherwise it will work. Are this means, that what I like to have (named quotes), is not possible?

Comment: I said no such thing and what I said meant no such thing! I just meant: you have to use the specified syntax. For an explanation of why it matters that you use the specified syntax in this case, please see my edit below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does not follow the syntax specified.

Working with a more minimal example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (0,0) edge ["My name is Harry."{name=Harry}] (1,1);
  \draw (Harry.south west) rectangle (Harry.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Harry]

When you say

```
<options>, "<text>"
```

`<options>` apply to the `edge` not the `edge quotes`. You must use

```
"<text>"<options>
```

as the manual says if you want `<options>` to apply to the `edge quotes` rather than the `edge`.

Compare

```
  \path (0,0) edge [blue, "My name is Harry."{name=Harry, red}] (1,1);
```

[image: red Harry]

which applies `red` to `My name is Harry.` and `blue` to the `edge`. Often, of course, this difference is irrelevant because nodes on paths inherit attributes from those paths. So if you just say

```
  \path (0,0) edge [blue, "My name is Harry."{name=Harry}] (1,1);
```

both `Harry` and `edge` will be `blue`.

[image: blue Harry]

But this is not because `blue` applies directly to `Harry` but only because nodes on paths inherit colours from those paths by default. However, names are not inherited in this way. Hence, if you want to *name* `Harry` rather than *colouring* him, you must use the syntax specified in the manual.

Comment: Dear @cfr, your explanation is clear and easy to understand. I would be glad, if this explanation will appear in TikZ manual :). In it I was not able to find instructions, how to introduce names to quotes. Cited part from didn't tell me this. Thank you very much for help and sorry for not so minimal MWE.

Comment: @Zarko I had no idea how to do this until you posted your question and all I did was read the bits you quoted from the manual. I didn't look anywhere else. I just followed what you'd posted. I haven't said anything you didn't include from the manual in your question. Honestly, I haven't. Look at the syntax the manual gives. You just slot the things in. That's all.

Comment: you are more smart than me :). Just now I edit my question and made code minimal (based on your answer). Thank you again.

Comment: @Zarko Nah. You just have a blind spot. Just take the syntax from the manual and put `My name is Harry.` instead of `<text>` and `{name=Harry}` instead of `<options>`. You'd reversed the order and put a comma between them :(. (You need the `{}` around `name=Harry` probably, just to stop the option getting broken at the `=`, although I didn't try without.

Comment: I just test your solution without curly braces around name. `\path (0,0) edge ["My name is Harry."name=Harry] (1,1); and it works! Thank you very much for your encouragement. It gives me new will/force to finish Viterbi diagrams (very small part from one of them I used in the first version of my MWE).