# How do I change the arrow length in a tikz file

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

**Edit:**
I have the following code in which I want to change the length of arrows:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=2pt,2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{decorate sep/.style 2 args=
    {decorate,decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=circle,shape size=#1,shape sep=#2}}}
\tikzset{>={Latex[width=1mm,length=3mm]}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{line} = [line width=.4pt]
    \tikzstyle{line1} = [->,line width=.2pt]
    
    \def\r{0.5pt} %define the radius of spot
    \def\ax{10.2} %define the length of x-axis
    \def\ay{4} %define the length of y-axis
    \def\x{9} %define the length of x
    \def\y{3} %define the height of T=1
    \def\z{0.7} %define the height between the arrow and label
        
    \draw[arrows=<->,line width=0.6pt]
    (0,\ay) coordinate node [below left] {$T$} -- (0,0) coordinate node[below] {$0$} -- (\ax, 0) coordinate node [below left] {$x$};

    \draw[line] (0,\y) -- (2,\y) -- (4,0);
    \draw[line] (2,0) -- (4,\y) -- (5,\y) -- (7,0);
    \draw[line] (5,0) -- (7,\y) -- (\x,\y);
    \draw[densely dotted] (\x,\y) -- (\x,0);
    
    \node[below] at (2,0) {$1.6$};
    \node[below] at (4,0) {$1.7$};
    \node[below] at (5,0) {$1.75$};
    \node[below] at (7,0) {$1.85$};
    \node[below] at (\x,0) {$2$};

    \node[left] at (0,\y) {$1$};
    \node[left] at (0,\y/2) {$0.5$};
    
    \draw[line1] (1.2, \y+\z) -- (1,\y);
        \node[above] at (1.2, \y+\z) {$short$};
    \draw[line1] (4.7, \y+\z) -- (4.5,\y);
        \node[above] at (4.7, \y+\z) {$medium$};
    \draw[line1] (8.2, \y+\z) -- (8,\y);
        \node[above] at (8.2, \y+\z) {$tall$};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to change length of arrows at the last three lines, e.g. "\draw[line1] (1.2, \y+\z) -- (1,\y)...", but I am not sure how to do it and need help. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide an MW, which reproduce your problem. Length of an arrow is determined by coordinates of their start and end or do talking about length of arrows heads?

Comment: Is this question about `shorten <=...` and `shorten >=...` keys?

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

Instead arrows are used modified pin in nodes placed on path of fuzzy functions. By this the diagram code is much shorter:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=2pt,2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
aligned pin/.style args = {[#1]#2:#3}% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367130
    {pin={[pin edge={{Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}-,
                     semithick, draw=black, shorten <=2pt},%
           coordinate,
           label={[%
                append after command={%
                node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,%font=...
                     at=(\tikzlastnode.#2),%
                     anchor=#1,%
                    ]{#3}%
                }%
            ]center:{}}%
         ]#2:{}}%
    },
          pin distance = 7mm,
            lbl/.style = {inner sep=0pt, 
                          aligned pin={[south west,xshift=-1ex]60:#1}},
           line/.style = {},
                        ]
    \def\r{0.5pt} %define the radius of spot
    \def\ax{10.2} %define the length of x-axis
    \def\ay{4} %define the length of y-axis
    \def\x{9} %define the length of x
    \def\y{3} %define the height of T=1
    \def\z{0.7} %define the height between the arrow and label
% axis
    \draw[arrows=<->,line width=0.6pt]
    (0,\ay) coordinate node [below left] {$T$} -- (0,0)   node[below] {$0$} 
                                               -- (\ax,0) node[below left] {$x$};
% fuzzy functions
\draw[line width=.4pt] 
    (0,\y) -- node[lbl=short] {} (2,\y) -- (4,0) node[below] {1.7}
    (2,0) node[below] {1.6}   -- (4,\y) -- node[lbl=medium] {} (5,\y)
                              -- (7, 0) node[below] {1.85}
    (5,0) node[below] {1.75}  -- (7,\y) -- node[lbl=tall] {} (\x,\y);
\draw[densely dotted] (\x,\y) -- (\x,0) node[below] {2};

    \node[left] at (0,\y) {$1$};
    \node[left] at (0,\y/2) {$0.5$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, I want to keep long arrows on x and y axis, but have 3 short arrows below labels.

Comment: As far as I see (well, I use glasses ...) last three arrows on my images are shorter for 2pt. However, the code is a bit more advanced then yours. To make just one arrow shorter, use @Luis Turcio comment.

Answer (score 2):

Principle to draw shorter line as are follows from given coordinates is use the option `\shorten > = <amount>` (to make arrows shorten on destination coordinate) and `shorten < = <amount>` (to make it shorted on the start coordinate). For illustration serve the following example:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=2pt,2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[shorten > = 1cm, -Straight Barb]      
            (0,0) -- (2,0); 
\draw[red]  (0,0.2) -- (2,0.2);   
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This concept you can use at arrow of your choice (i.e. at last three arrows as I use in my first answer, where instead separated explicit drawn arrows and nodes above them are used `pin` which is in its style definition shortened for 2pt).